# How to do part of speech tagging and lemmatization autmatically

Tags: python, wordnet, lemmatization, part-of-speech

We can use wordnet in python.

Suppose we are give text :

```
"International companies had interns"
```

Then we can manually do part of speech tagging :

```
tokens = ["International","companies","had","interns"]
word_type = {"International":wordnet.ADJ,"companies":wordnet.NOUN,"had":wordnet.VERB,"interns":wordnet.NOUN}

lemmatizer=WordNetLemmatizer()
token_list=[]
for token in tokens:
    token_list.append(lemmatizer.lemmatize(token,word_type[token]))
```

I want to avoid the manual part of code and do that automatically :

```
word_type = {"International":wordnet.ADJ,"companies":wordnet.NOUN,"had":wordnet.VERB,"interns":wordnet.NOUN}
#need to do above automatically from given text
```

Comment: You need to do POS tagging and tokenization before running the lemmatizer.  Wordnet doesn't do this but I think NLTK has a POS tagger and tokenizer.  A better option would be to use SPaCy.  SPaCy is most peoples' choice for this type of work, and you can find examples in their docs on how to do this in just a few lines of code.

Comment: @bivouac0 Thanks. I have seen some of the library where we can automatically do POS tagging. I will try with them.